# Django-Secretballot does not work?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-sessions

I am using [Django-secretballot](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-secretballot) app which allows anonymous voting. First we register a model for secret voting and then there is a function add_vote() which takes 2 arguments. 'Token' and vote value(+1 or -1).

from [docs](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-secretballot/blob/master/README.rst):

**add_vote:**

function that takes a token and a vote (+1 or -1) and adds or updates the vote for said     token (can be renamed by passing add_vote_name parameter to enable_voting_on)

What am I supposed to pass in as 'Token'? 
I used this in my views.py

```
t=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
feed.add_vote(t,+1)
```

Yet it does not work. I mean if I try voting from different machines, only first vote gets counted. But it does not get incremented when other vote for that same feed.

Anyone who has used this app or figured out what I am doing wrong by checking the [doc](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-secretballot/blob/master/README.rst). Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author and although I haven't actively developed it recently I hope you find it useful.

token can be any unique string you require, generally speaking what you have should work but there's a chance you're behind a proxy or there's another issue with REMOTE_ADDR in your server config (which is beyond what I'd be able to assist with)

Check that the value of REMOTE_ADDR is actually changing, also consider using a combination of  REMOTE_ADDR and something else like a User Agent or unique value stored in a cookie.

Comment: Got it working.. prob was indeed with the server conf. n thnx for helping and also for creating such a nice app.  kudos :)